# Forecasting library plot

Tags: r, plot, forecasting

Im looking for the name of the library capable of making this plot.

[image]

The forecasting bit is I'm what I'm interested. Is it Forecast library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the time-series plot is from the forecast library. You get that sort of plot when you plot a `forecast object`. Look at `?forecast`. For example:

```
install.packages('forecast')
library(forecast)
fit <- StructTS(WWWusage,"level")
plot(forecast(fit))
```

The rest of the fancy stuff i.e. interactivity is most likely `shiny` magic, but I think you are interested only in the main plot.

Comment: Thank you sir. Will up vote in 5 minutes. I just wanted to know the library name so I can start doing a shiny app. Thanks

Comment: @TomasAlonsoRehor no problem, eeeerrr, if the answer given is what you were looking for, you should `accept` by clicking the tick button below the `downvote` button, `upvote` is just to say that you liked an answer.

Comment: Yeah I know. There is a time limit tho to tick the answer green and I was few minutes under. Its sorted now tho. thanks